# Get OAuth Token Programmatically Using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, google-api-java-client

I modified [this piece of code from google api client](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/PasswordTokenRequest) and have successfully used it to get a token from a 3rd party (non-google) OAuth service:

```
TokenResponse response =
      new PasswordTokenRequest(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(),
          new GenericUrl("https://server.example.com/token"), "johndoe", "A3ddj3w")
          .setRedirectUri("https://client.example.com/rd")
          .setClientAuthentication(
              new BasicAuthentication("s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw")).execute();
  System.out.println("Access token: " + response.getAccessToken());
```

Is there a way to achieve this programmatically using something from Spring Security API? I've looked at tutorials, I've seen [OAuth2AuthorizationRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.0.M1/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/core/endpoint/OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.html/) and other related classes, but I'm stumped.

I'm beginning to think that Spring Security is not to be used for this, and is better suited for creating an OAuth server and its client definitions, not the client implementation.